# Discrete measures and discrete kernels

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory

This is a cross-post from [math.stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113440/discrete-measures-and-discrete-kernels). Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $\mu$ be the probability measure on $\mathbb R^d$ defined by $\mu=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}\delta_{x_k}$ for some sequence $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb R^d,$ where we denote by $\delta_x$ the point measure at $x.$ For each $x\in\text{supp}\mu$ assume we are given a sequence $(y_l(x))_{l\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ and define a probability measure on $\mathbb R^d$ by $K(x,\cdot):=\sum_{l=1}^\infty 2^{-l}\delta_{y_l(x)}(\cdot).$ My question is, does $K$ define a probability kernel, i.e. is $K$ measurable in $x$? If it is true, we can define a probability measure on $\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d$ by $$(\mu\otimes K)(B)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d}1_B(x,y)K(x,dy)\mu(dx),$$
for $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d).$ But is it clear that the resulting measure is still discrete?

Edit: By $\text{supp}\mu,$ we denote the smallest closed set $A$ in $\mathbb R^d$ with $\mu(A)=1.$

Comment: If I took it apart properly, then the measure of $B$ equals $\sum 2^{-k-l}$, where the sum is over those $k,l$ for which $(x_k,y_l(x_k))\in B$. This is manifestly still a pure point measure; it is supported by the countable set $(x_k,y_l(x_k))$.

Comment: Well, $K(x,\cdot)$ is also defined for $x\neq x_k.$ So the question is, if $K$ is still measurable in $x$

Comment: I now suspect I don't fully understand your notation/terminology ("support" for example). I'll leave the comment up anyway.

Comment: I added the definition of support.

Comment: To have measurability with respect to $x$ you should *assume* measurability of the functions $y_l$. Then $K$ should be indeed a kernel.